# T-SQL Import CSV with Varied Number of Columns

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a CSV with approx 60k lines by 250 columns.  However if the ending columns were null, the commas were not exported (see below).

```
a,b,c,d,e,f  
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c  
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

So when I go to import this via SSIS or BCP, I get overflow errors.
I thought I've had this problem before and SSIS would catch my back. :-/

Is there a simple solution to this, such as a BCP switch?  Or do I need to do some sort of text manipulation to add the missing commas to the end before importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do quick search in stackoverflow or google you will get answer.

here is link, hope it helps you.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssis+variable+column+flat+file